# error nf_conntrack table full without iptables running

Tags: linux, iptables, ip-conntrack

Why I am getting "nf_conntrack table full" error in syslog even when I am not running iptables?

I believe if iptables not running then nf_conntrack shouldn't used, even it's loaded into the kernel.

Comment: do any of these answers help? http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/43205/nf-conntrack-table-full-dropping-packet

Comment: But even if you don't use iptable does kernel drop packet of just `nf_conntrack` module is loaded?

Comment: unload the kernel modules